# Generate OpenCL Names List

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

Is there a way to generate a list of the names of variables/functions for the current OpenCL version?

For example, I want to create arrays like these:

```
constants = ['M_E_F', 'M_LOG2E_F', 'M_LOG10E_F', 'M_LN2_F', 'M_LN10_F', 'M_PI_F', 'M_PI_2_F', 'M_PI_4_F', 'M_1_PI_F', 'M_2_PI_F', 'M_2_SQRTPI_F', 'M_SQRT2_F', 'M_SQRT1_2_F']
common_functions = ['clamp', 'degrees', 'max', 'min', 'mix', 'radians', 'sign', 'smoothstep', 'step']
```

Would I have to use a script to parse the man pages?  Or copy/paste from documentation?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Just some terminology: platforms don't contain functions or variables. You're talking about the OpenCL language specification, and these are fixed for a given OpenCL version.

Comment: Oops, apologies, I will correct that error!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way other than reading the spec.